# How would I find the number of 0s with 6 or more other 0s connected in a number of different data frames at once in R?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

How would I find the number of 0s in a number of different data frames saved within different csv files in a working directory with 6 or more 0s also connected to it in the spot above, below, left, right and diagonally of it?

I have read in all the csv files in the directory using:

```
csv_files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
csv_files <- lapply(csv_files, read.delim)
```

And the matrices inside these csv files look something like this:

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

But some are considerably larger (i.e. 50 x 50). Is there a away of doing this with all files at once?

[Example of situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IC6P9.png)

A reproducible example:

```
set.seed(99) # for reproducibility
mat <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 100, replace=TRUE), nrow=10) # sample matrix
mat

         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
  [1,]    1    1    1    0    1    0    0    0    0     0
  [2,]    0    1    1    1    0    1    0    1    1     0
  [3,]    1    1    1    0    1    0    0    0    0     1
  [4,]    1    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     0
  [5,]    1    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    0     1
  [6,]    0    1    1    1    1    0    0    1    1     1
  [7,]    0    0    1    0    0    1    1    0    0     0
  [8,]    1    1    1    1    0    1    0    1    0     0
  [9,]    1    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0     1
 [10,]    1    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    0     1

window <- matrix(rep(1,9), nrow=3) # window to count number of 1s
window

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1

window[2,2] <- 20  
window

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1   20    1
[3,]    1    1    1

 sum(sapply(1:(nrow(files)-2), function(i) t(sapply(1:(ncol(mat)-2), 
 function(j) sum(window * mat[i:(i+2),j:(j+2)])))) >= 6)

[1] 43
```

Comment: So you are looking for "crosses" of 0, where each leg of the cross has at least 6 zeros?

Comment: Or are you looking for at least six of the eight surrounding cells (including the diagonals) being zero?

Comment: @Ape I am looking for all 0s that have more than 6 0s connecting to it if any. Please see edited link I provided in my question above to gain a better understanding of what I'm looking for.

Comment: @AndrewGustar that is what I am looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach creates 8 auxiliary matrices, which are all shifted one  spot to the left / right / top / down, and then compares their matrix sum to a given number (here it is 2, since we are looking for no more than two `1` in the neighborhood of the central `0`)

```
MatrixWrapper = function(mat, layers = 1){
    mwrap = matrix(1, ncol = ncol(mat) + 2*layers, nrow = nrow(mat) + 2*layers)
    mwrap[layers+1:nrow(mat), layers+1:ncol(mat)] = mat
    mwrap
}    

FindClusters = function(mat){
    mat_wrapped = MatrixWrapper(mat, 1)
    submatrices = lapply(0:8, function(k){
        mat_wrapped[1:nrow(mat)+k %% 3, 1:ncol(mat)+k %/% 3]
    })

    Reduce("+", submatrices) <= 2 & mat == 0
}

suitable_zeros = lapply(csv_files, FindClusters) # indicate which 0s meet the condition 
lapply(suitable_zeros, sum) # count the suitable 0s per matrix
```

It should be reasonably fast even for large matrices (my PC runs it in ~0.1s with a single 1000x1000 matrix). The result of `FindClusters()` applied on your presented matrix is:

```
#     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
#[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#[6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#[7,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#[8,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#[9,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#[10] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: when I try out your code I get the error `Incorrect number of dimensions` on the following line `suitable_zeros = lapply(csv_files, FindClusters)` @Ape

Comment: @Rebecca Try converting your list to matrices: `csv_files_matrices = lapply(csv_files, as.matrix)` and then `suitable_zeros = lapply(csv_files_matrices, FindClusters)`. The code works with matrices, while `read.delim` reads the csvs as data.frames (which I didn't realize).

Comment: @Rebecca For matrices, the code should work, e.g. using your reproducible example: `csv_files = list(); csv_files[[1]] = mat; csv_files[[2]] = t(mat); lapply(csv_files, FindClusters)`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to write a function to count the number of zeros with at least six surrounding zeros...

```
set.seed(99)                                               #for reproducibility
mat <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 100, prob=c(0.8,0.2), 
              replace=TRUE),
              nrow=10)                                     #sample matrix

window <- matrix(rep(1,9), nrow=3)                         #window to count number of 1s
window[2,2] <- 20                                          #penalty for 1 in centre

mat
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0     0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     1
 [3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [6,]    1    0    0    0    1    1    1    0    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1
 [8,]    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    0    0     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     0
[10,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1     0

window
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1   20    1
[3,]    1    1    1
```

This function will then count the number of 1s in each 3x3 window, with a penalty of 20 if there is a 1 in the centre, and return the number of entries in the matrix for which this total is less than three:

```
check_zeros <- function(mat){
   sum(sapply(1:(nrow(mat)-2),
                 function(i) t(sapply(1:(ncol(mat)-2),
                                      function(j) sum(window * mat[i:(i+2),j:(j+2)])
                                     )
                              )
              ) < 3)
    }

check_zeros(mat)
[1] 39
```

Now you can process all of your matrices with

```
sapply(csv_files, check_zeros)
```

Comment: @AndrewGustar I updated my question with a reproducible example following your code but I can't figure out why I get 43 in this example? Can you please help?

Comment: @Rebecca As you are now testing for >=6, the 20 in the middle of the window matrix will mean that all of the middle-1s are counted, plus any middle-zeros with 6 or more 1s around them. My test was for <3 ones around a zero, which is different.